# How do you compare different git merging strategies in case of renaming files

Tags: git, git-merge

Why can recursive merge strategy in git detect and handle file renames better than other strategies?  How is it different from other merging strategies?

Comment: It's not a matter of better; the resolve strategy simply doesn't implement rename detection at all.

Comment: thank you @EdwardThomson but my real question is how it is implemented that it support such thing. I don't want to know about the specific implementation, just the idea behind the algorithm.